# Everything works but the Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, openweathermap

Making a call to the openweather API.  When I input the URL into a browser, I can see the JSON object.  However my ajax below is not allowing anything to appear in my HTML. Even if I want to document.write the entire json object, I cannot. I can output the lat and long just find so the geolocation is working.  Not sure what's wrong with this code.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 header">
    <h1>My Location</h1>
  </div>
    <div class="row text-center box">
      <div class="col-lg-12" id="data">Lat Long</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(main); 
  }
});
function main(position){
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat      + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=[redacted key]";
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: api,
    success: function(data) {
        city = data.name;
        $("#data").html(city);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console about cross-domain requests?

Comment: Did you get an error in the console about trying to access HTTP from HTTPS? (Seriously, you **need** to look at the console to see error messages before asking on SO).

Comment: I did not get a console error messgae

Comment: You need to use jsonp

Comment: @Andy — That seems unlikely, but if it is the case, then add an error handler as well as a success handler. See what jQuery has to say about it. Also add console.log statements to make sure that the main function is being run.

Comment: @RobertRocha — Why? The OP said they didn't get a cross origin error message and the URL they are accessing doesn't appear to support JSONP (which is a horrible hack that we no longer need because we have CORS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$.getJson` instead of `$.ajax`: 
      `$.getJSON( {
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: api,
      success: function(data) {
        city = data.name;
        $("#data").html(city);
    }`

In the HTML, make sure to add jquery:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="a.js"></script>` // whatever your js file is named

Without modifying your code, the page asked to access my location and then displayed my current city. I'm not sure what it is supposed to output though. What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: I'm expecting the city to be the output.  Did your code work in Chrome?  I just tried it no luck.  Here is the jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lx24c5mu/

Comment: Yes, this worked with Chrome and Firefox. In the HTML, I added: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="a.js"></script>`. Perhaps there is an issue with your scripts, is jquery referenced before your js file?

Comment: Thanks.  It's working in Safari but not in Chrome.  Going to chalk this up to a possible geolocation issue in Chrome.  But you change from .ajax to .getJSON definitely worked.  Assume that is because the data is json formatted no need to use ajax?

Comment: So I ran into 2 problems.  If you switch the JSFiddle to a http link and test the code you will get the following error pertaining to chrome navigator:  getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See link for more details.  So, then you may switch it and notice that chrome does not like it if you try to use an http api request when on an HTTPS page.  You will get a Mixed Content message...Sounds like you need a https API (more secure API).

Comment: What does your jquery reference look like? Try using the Cloudflare jquery referenced above. It should be working.

Comment: I was using JQuery 3.0.0 for my tests. I think ultimately that you cannot use an http api when using the geolocation feature of chrome as it requires https for that feature.  Thus you will run into one of the two problems I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your ajax call.

You code seems to work pretty good with hardcoded coordinates and also works in its current form on all other browsers besides Chrome.

If you want to use the geolocation on the newer versions of Google Chrome your host would have to be a secure one (HTTPS).

**Chrome warning:**

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.